# com.facebook.widget class is not instantiated in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am making an android app where I want to do login through Facebook. I did every step as suggested in **facebook  developer page**, but I got following error :

> com.facebook.widget.LoginButton is not instantiated

But I instantiated in my activity.

**my xml code`**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include

        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar">

    </include>
    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="65dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:hint="Enter Username"
        android:id="@+id/et1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:hint="Enter Password"
        android:id="@+id/et2"
       android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bu1"
        android:text="Login"

        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     </LinearLayout>
      < /LinearLayout>`
```

**my activity code**

`

```
 package com.manali.vivek.userregistration;


    public class userLogin extends Activity {


    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;

    EditText et1,et2;
    Button bu1;

     private TextView tv1,tv2;

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;
    String nameT;
    String passwordT;
    @Override


     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.user_login);
               et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et2);


        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new
        FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                info.setText(
                        "User ID: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                + "\n" +
                                "Auth Token: "
                                + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                );
            }


            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
            }


            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
            }
        });


        bu1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bu1);
      tv1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(userLogin.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);


            }
        });
        tv2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        nameT= et1.getText().toString().trim();
        passwordT= et2.getText().toString().trim();
        bu1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getCustomerData();

            }
        });

    }
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent 
    data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
    private void getCustomerData(){
        class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = 
    ProgressDialog.show(userLogin.this,"Fetching...","Wait...",false,false);

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                showData(s);

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();
                String s =   
     

                return s;
            }
        }

        GetData ge = new GetData();
        ge.execute();
    }

    private void showData(String json){

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Fetch.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);
            JSONObject c = result.getJSONObject(0);
            String id=c.getString(Fetch.TAG_ID);
           String name = c.getString(Fetch.TAG_NAME);
            String password = c.getString(Fetch.TAG_PASS);
            String mailId = c.getString(Fetch.TAG_MAIl);
            String x=et1.getText().toString();
            String y=et2.getText().toString();

            if(name.equals(x) &&password.equals(y)){


                    startActivity(new Intent(userLogin.this,secondStart.class));



                // Intent i=new Intent(this,userInfo.class);
                //i.putExtra("name",name);
               // i.putExtra("password",password);
               // i.putExtra("mailId",mailId);
                //startActivity(i);
            }






        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }




    }
`
```

**my manifest code**

`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
        android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".userLogin"
        android:label=" Login  "
        android:noHistory="true" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label=" register  " >
    </activity>`
```

Comment: where is your gradle file?which sdk version you used?

Comment: Use Graph api of facebook you will get each and everything you need from facebook